# Create a zoomable starfield

Tags: particles, shaders

### Background

Almost all stars are so distant that they cannot be optically resolved, and instead appear as point sources. (Here's the short [list of exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stars_with_resolved_images).)

This means that if you look up at a spot in the night sky with your naked eyes, and then look at the same spot with binoculars or a telescope, most stars will not appear *larger*, only more discrete (because the apparent distances between them will be magnified) and [brighter](https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-resources/astronomy-questions-answers/if-stars-appear-as-points-why-are-some-stars-big-and-some-small-in-different-images/).

### Problem

I would like to create a space scene (in Cycles) where the same object is shown zoomed in and zoomed out (i.e. with different focal lengths) against a background of stars.

How can I create a star field where each star will appear as a point source, and not change in apparent size when zooming?

For examples of the approximate effect I'm looking for, see this *Expanse* S5E7 [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuqEX1PnG9I#t=41s), particularly the zoom shots at 0:42 and 0:57.

Environment textures wouldn't work because they're just pixels, and when the camera zooms in, the pixels would be magnified. I *think* that generated particles would have the same problem, though perhaps I could animate the particle sizes to shrink them down as the camera zooms in.

Comment: Does the camera only zoom, or does it also move and rotate?
If it only zooms, you could use the camera mapping for your backdrop image

Answer (score 4):

From the experience with my camera at home, zooming in on a starry sky from 28mm up to 400mm the stars definitely become bigger, too - there are still no observable details, but zooming in makes the "blotches" larger. And another thing, zoomed in you will see more stars than zoomed out, because the much smaller ones are magnified as well. Of course this is also depending on how fast your lens is, if it doesn't get enough light zooming in results in darker, less visible stars. But the size definitely changes.

So if you zoom in on an object that's further away instead of moving towards it, the relative position of the starry background doesn't change much, so you're right that you'd see fewer stars (of the bright ones you're seeing zoomed out, but more darker ones might appear).

To avoid having pixelated stars I'm not using an *Environment Texture* for this, I'm creating a fully procedural background with muktiple *Voronoi Textures* at different scales. Plugging the *Distance* output into a *Color Ramp* you get very small circles if you set the ramp's left slider to white, the right one to black and bring it very close to the left. I multiply the ramps' outputs with different values so that the larger stars are brighter than the smaller stars.

The best is to decide how large you make the different star sizes when zoomed in. If they become invisible when zoomed out, you might make them brighter by multiplying with a higher value or compromise by tweaking the size a little bit. Here is a typical setup I use:

[image]

Of course you can add even more *Voronoi Textures* with varying sizes or even colorize the stars with this. That's one of the reasons I'm using *4D* instead of *3D* in the voronoi settings. If I like to have different colored stars but at the same size, I duplicate the node and change the *W* value.

Comment: very cool result!

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, there is a way to use environmental texture and have it not be distorted. Instead of moving camera closer to the object or zooming in using focal length, you have the camera stay in place, and move/scale the object you want to “zoom in” on, simulating the effect.

Now, this solution might turn out way harder than it sounds like. I’ve never tried this before, so I can’t inform you on the nuances this approach requires. I wish you to figure it out.

**Edit**:
Re-reading your question and the comment I realise that yes, my idea is not applicable here. But I think now I understand.

Animating the particle sizes, as you said, might be the way, but there should be an easier solution though, the one that would not require you to scale the whole background each time.
Maybe some scripting can automate that, but I'm no programmer.

Another thing that came to my mind is to add the background in "postproduction". Have it be done separately(not in Blender, perhaps? I'm thinking vector graphics editors) and just layer the rendered starships animation on top?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that would work. **(1)** If the object moves but there's no zoom, the field of view stays the same. When zooming, I would expect the field of view to _shrink_ (so I'd see fewer of the stars). **(2)** Changing the distance between the camera and the object has a _very_ different visual effect compared to changing the focal length. See an explanation here: https://vimeo.com/blog/post/zoom-vs-moving-camera-whats-the-difference/